# DevExpress XtraGrid ExportToXls is not working on all desktops: what are its prerequisites?

Tags: devexpress, export-to-excel, xtragrid

What are the prerequisites for the XtraGrid's ExportToXls method?  To accomplish this, does some DLL have to be included in addition to the XtraGrid DLL?  Does the export use Office interop behind the scenes? I am trying to get to the bottom of a problem where it works on some machines and fails on others.

Comment: Provide more detailed error information to get the help..

Comment: @SLaks: No error, just silent failure, despite try/catch where I display an exception message to screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **What are the prerequisites for the XtraGrid's ExportToXls method?
>
>    To accomplish this, does some DLL have to be included in addition to the
>   XtraGrid DLL?**

***Ans:***

***Source***: [Export Methods and Settings](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2536) and [GridControl.ExportToXls(String,XlsExportOptions) Method](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridGridControl_ExportToXlstopic837)

*The XtraGrid control provides a set of methods that allow you to [export data in various formats](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2536). These methods export data using routines implemented in the XtraPrinting Library.*

*[GridControl.ExportToXls(String)](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridGridControl_ExportToXlstopic833) Method method indirectly calls the DevExpress.XtraPrinting.PrintingSystemBase.ExportToXls method of the XtraPrinting Library. If this library is not available the method does nothing. For details on the ExportToXls method see the DevExpress.XtraPrinting.PrintingSystemBase.ExportToXls topic*

[image: XtraPrinting Library Ref]

> **Does the export use Office interop behind the scenes?**

Regarding this you need to [ask the DevExpress guys](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Create) for clearification. As per my understanding, it does not require any Microsoft Office interop dll references.

Comment: Thank you. I will have to ask about the difference between `DevExpress.Printing.v11.2.Core` and `DevExpress.XtraPrinting`. Unfortunately, we are still at v10, and only the latter is in the Components\Sources folder.

Answer (score 0):

The [GridControl.ExportToXls](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridGridControl_ExportToXlstopic) method indirectly calls the [PrintingSystemBase.ExportToXls](http://help.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressXtraPrintingPrintingSystemBase_ExportToXlstopic750) method of the DevExpress Printing Library (DevExpress.Printing.v12.2.Core.dll). If this library is not available the method does nothing. Thus you should only reference the DevExpress.Printing.v12.2.Core.dll library in your project. There is no any Office references needed.

For general information on exporting data in the GridControl refer to [Export Overview](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument995).

To get **guaranteed assistance** with your specific problem contact with [DevExpress Support](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center) directly.